# Possible to determine Liveagent API endpoint host programmatically?

Tags: liveagent

When you create a Liveagent Deployment in the UI, you are presented with a script snippet to paste into the page where you will deploy Liveagent; the first line includes a reference to the liveagent endpoint host, for example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la6cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/29.0/deployment.js'></script>
```

Is there a way to determine the liveagent hostname (`c.la6cs.salesforceliveagent.com` in the code above) programmatically?  I can query for all of the other key values - org id, deployment id, even the id of my chat buttons.

I am aware that I could store the endpoint URL in a custom setting, however, this requires maintenance any time the code is deployed to a new org.  Is there any way to determine the correct url on the fly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no there is not a way to do it.  The recommended approach is to use what you are already aware of -- Custom Settings.  See [this #askforce tweet](https://twitter.com/JohnDTheMaven/status/448892754849177600) responded to by the product manager at Salesforce.

> Is there a way to determine LiveAgent API Endpoint from Apex or JS?  liveagent.init(*endpoint*,chakey,org)

Response:

> Unfortunately, no, not today. Best practice is to store these in a custom setting in the org.